# Skyrim undead characters not moving at all

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently got Skyrim with all of its addons on Steam and started a new game.

Everything works perfectly except for undead characters such as Draugrs and Skeletons which are frozen in place and not moving at all until I kill them.

I've found posts of people having the same problem but they seem to be using animation mods such as FNIS ( http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/11811 ), which I don't. The only mods I use are for the UI (SkyUI and the necessary SKSE), textures (Skyrim HD, Enhanced Blood) and for the map (Quality World Map), and I don't have any `meshes/actor` folder.

I tried disabling each addon separately but it didn't fix the problem.

Anyone knows what could cause this?

Comment: You should definitely install the unofficial patches. If they don't help, try disabling all mods.

Comment: I simply reinstalled the game, loaded my save without mods and put them back one by one. Problem is fixed now, I guess that's the magic of Bethesda's games. The unofficial patches are still a good idea though, I'll install them, thanks.

Comment: You should make the above comment an answer and close the question, as it has been 'solved.'